Why does String.Format("text{0}", x1, x2, x3) take way more memory than String.Format("text {0}", new object{x1, x2, x3})?
I need to test how different ways of string formatting affect the performance. And I found a surprising result. Let me explain with two test cases:
// Test Case 2
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    var message = string.Format("Test Message{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", int1, int2, int3, int4, int5);
}

// Test Case 3
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    var message = string.Format("Test Message{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", new object[] { int1, int2, int3, int4, int5 });
}

Output
Test Case 2 - Elapsed Time: 1770 ms
Test Case 2 - Memory Used: 28528 bytes
Test Case 3 - Elapsed Time: 1685 ms
Test Case 3 - Memory Used: 360 bytes

The Question
As you can see, memory usage is ~100 times more in Test Case 2 (where string.Format uses arguments directly) compared to Test Case 3 (where arguments are wrapped in an object[] explicitly).
But why?
As I understand, string.Format should implicitly convert arguments into an object[] anyway. What is happening here that causes such a drastic difference in memory usage?
I am expecting to see nearly equal memory usage.
Notes

int1 = 1, int2 = 2 ...
to track time I use stopWatch
to track memory I use beforeMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true); and compare the values before and after the execution

Full code that I use for "benchmarking":
using System.Diagnostics;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //var fileStream = new FileStream(
        //"C:\\Users\\osavytskyy\\Documents\\Projects\\TestScript\\file.txt",
        //FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
        //FileAccess.ReadWrite,
        //FileShare.None); // Prevents other processes from reading or writing

        //Console.Read();
        //fileStream.Dispose();

        var int1 = 1;
        var int2 = 2;
        var int3 = 3;
        var int4 = 4;
        var int5 = 5;

        var filestream = new LogStreamFile("C:\\Projects\\TestProj\\file.txt");

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        // Test Case 1
        long beforeMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            var message = string.Format("Test Message");
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Test Case 1 - Elapsed Time: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
        Console.WriteLine($"Test Case 1 - Memory Used: {GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - beforeMemory} bytes");
       
        // Test Case 2
        beforeMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            var message = string.Format("Test Message{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", int1, int2, int3, int4, int5);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Test Case 2 - Elapsed Time: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
        Console.WriteLine($"Test Case 2 - Memory Used: {GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - beforeMemory} bytes");
        
        // Test Case 3
        beforeMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            //var arg = new object[] { var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 };
            var message = string.Format("Test Message{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", new object[] { int1, int2, int3, int4, int5 });
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Test Case 3 - Elapsed Time: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
        Console.WriteLine($"Test Case 3 - Memory Used: {GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - beforeMemory} bytes");
        

        // Test Case 4
        beforeMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Start();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            var message = $"Test Message{int1}{int2}{int3}{int4}{int5}";
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Test Case 4 - Elapsed Time: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
        Console.WriteLine($"Test Case 4 - Memory Used: {GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - beforeMemory} bytes");
        
    }
}



You're currently forcing a full collection when you take the second measurement, so you never actually see the total memory cost. Do GC.GetTotalMemory(false) - beforeMemory instead of GC.GetTotalMemory(true) - beforeMemory and you'll get comparable measurements. You might also want to take the measurement immediately after stopping the stopwatch (as opposed to waiting until after the first Console.WriteLine call after)

Honestly, I would recommend using Benchmark.Net to get some more reliable numbers. That will give you accurate times and memory usage. The difference between the two can be seen if you see that lowered code. For example

Thank you @DavidG, I initially created this post as a way hoping I would learn some underlying magic of c#, but instead I learned that I need to invest some time into learning proper benchmarking technics
